# same values on dropdown menu using v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm just starting using Vue.js to do a points counter app and I'm having troubles with v-for loop and dropdown menu.

I have an array of players in my Vue.js app :

```js
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#leaderboard',
    data: {
        players: [{'name': 'Quentin', 'points': 0}, {'name': 'Kevin', 'points': 0}]
    },
    computed: {
        orderPlayers: function(){
            const compare = (a, b) => {
                return a.points - b.points;
            }
            console.log(this.players.sort(compare).reverse());
            return this.players.sort(compare).reverse();
        }
    }
})
```

And I am trying to display my elements in a div sorted by number of points like this :

```html
    <div id="leaderboard-wrapper">
        <span>Classement :</span>
        <div id="leaderboard">
            <div v-for="(player, index) in orderPlayers" :key="index" class="element">
                <span id="name">{{ player.name }}</span>
                <span id="points">{{ player.points }}<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></span>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="showDropdown()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></button>
                    <div id="actionDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#" @click="player.points+=2">A marqué 2</a>
                        <a href="#" @click="player.points +=5">A marqué 5</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when I hit the button "A marqué 2" for Kevin, it is the points counter of Quentin that increment.

I made some tests and researches and I discover that the "player" value in the #actionDropdown div is the same for the two players. Here, player points on the player Quentin for the two elements.

Did someone have an idea to fix this problem ?

Thank you in advance ! :)

Comment: I've created a fiddle, and I don't see any proplem. When one presses the button "A marqué 2" for Kevin at some point Kevin gets more points that Quentin since you're sorting the player depending of their points Kevin and Quentin swap places.

Answer (score 0):

***Suggestion :*** Instead of `reverse()` the sorted array, You can sort the array in descending order. Your compare function should be like this **:**

```
const compare = (a, b) => {
    return a.points - b.points;
}
```

Also, Your code is working fine, I did not see any issue in `points` value increment. One thing which I noticed is that as we are doing sorting inside the `computed` property. Hence, on clicking `A marqué 2` or `A marqué 5`, points value of the respective player has been increased and sorted by default due to the computed property.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    players: [{'name': 'Quentin', 'points': 0}, {'name': 'Kevin', 'points': 0}]
  },
  computed: {
    orderPlayers: function(){
      const compare = (a, b) => {
        return b.points - a.points;
      }
      return this.players.sort(compare);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <span>Classement :</span>
  <div id="leaderboard">
    <div v-for="(player, index) in orderPlayers" :key="index" class="element">
      <span id="name">{{ player.name }}</span>
      <span id="points">{{ player.points }}<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" onclick="showDropdown()"><i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis-vertical"></i></button>
        <div id="actionDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#" @click="player.points+=2">A marqué 2</a>
          <a href="#" @click="player.points +=5">A marqué 5</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```